# Finding speed of an interval of 10 seconds

Tags: typescript, cordova, angular8, phonegap, ionic5

I have an angular ionic 5 app running on a cordova android emulator. What I need to do is use the ionic Geolocation plugin to find the speed of the user. I need to record the user's speed every second, and make sure it falls in the range of 0.7 < x < 2.5 m/s. If it does not, continue recording every second until it does. I need to record 10 valid speed measurements using this method. Then determine the average speed from that set of data.

I can include a set-up of my current typescript code for my app:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Geolocation } from '@ionic-native/geolocation/ngx';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
    styleUrls: ['home.page.scss'],
})
export class HomePage {
    framework = 'At exact boarding time';

    constructor(private geolocation: Geolocation) {}

    latitude: any = 0; //latitude
    longitude: any = 0; //longitude
    speed: any = 1; //speed

    choices = {
        timeout: 10000, 
        enableHighAccuracy: true, 
        maximumAge: 3600
    };

    average_walking_speed(){
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(this.choices).then((resp) => {
            this.speed = resp.coords.speed;
            console.log(this.speed);
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error getting speed', error);
        });
    }

    // use geolocation to get user's device coordinates
    getCurrentCoordinates() {
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
            this.latitude = resp.coords.latitude;
            this.longitude = resp.coords.longitude;
            this.speed = resp.coords.speed;
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error getting location', error);
        });

        document.getElementById("updater").innerHTML = ' ' + this.speed +" m/s"
    }    
}
```

You can see I currently record my position and speed, and it appears to be working. I just need to do this over an interval and find the average speed. I am new to typescript, so I am unsure how to proceed, tips would be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you try to solve this by using .watchPosition method of the plugin? there is no set frequency with it but in avg device yield new position (if changed) at about 1s interval.

Comment: I have been looking at .watchPosition, I am fairly new to typescript though. Could you give an example of how to implement it here and I could adapt it?

Comment: yeah i can stab it, can you help elaborate more about use case? what avg speed in 10s should give you? like what are you trying to achieve ideally

Comment: I am creating an app that monitors a users location in an airport. When they enter an airport, the location service turns on. Then, it starts tracking the speed over a span of 10 seconds. If the speed value is 0.7<speed<2.5m/s, store it, until we have 10 values stored. Find the average. This average speed will be used to estimate the travel time to the flight gate. This is a small part of a big project, so I just want to be able to find this average speed as the user moves, then display it in the html file of my app.

Comment: I see, so if your use case is for indoors, keep in mind that geolocation plugins will leverage cellId and wifi to pin location and precision in this case goes way down. I would double check what location sources this plugin blends before proceeding with implementation tbh. You might need something else to make it work (like step meter etc)

Comment: consider this: https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/pedometer, maybe combination of these 2 will help

Comment: Got you, I am more concerned with the speed parameter, the location is not my task to complete as of right now. I will keep it in mind though. I do not know how geolocation derives its speed parameter, but I have a hunch it is based off of the coordinates.